# Rvest html scrape returning no table

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

New to table scraping. Tried to look for a similar situation and found some threads that suggested it could be loaded through another language query (javascript or other), but not sure how to check for that.

Code I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(rvest)

response <- GET("https://covid19.humportal.org/activities?display=table&summary=disbursements&breakdown=country")

html <- content(response)

xml_structure(html)

# xpath below copied from inspect on google chrome
table <- html %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]')

# Other test with table class/id
content <- read_html('https://covid19.humportal.org/activities?display=table&summary=disbursements&breakdown=country')

test <- content %>% 
  html_nodes('table#__BVID__78.table.b-table.table-bordered.table.sm') %>%
  html_text()
```

table returns as a list of 0. test returns as an empty character value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a sidenote. the data in not embedded in  html. you will have to look for  other means

Comment: The page likely uses javascript to load the data. `rvest` can't run javascript. You'd either have to reverse engineer the specific site to figure out where they are pulling the data from or use something like RSelenium which allows you to pull data through a web browser which can run javascript.

Comment: the project seems to be open source with the data hosted [here](https://github.com/OCHA-DAP/covid19-data). Specifically [activities.json](https://github.com/OCHA-DAP/covid19-data/blob/gh-pages/activities.json)

Comment: Are you trying to download the excel file?